# When using weak or soft reference with a ReferenceQueue when is the object really removed from memory?

Tags: java, weak-references, soft-references

When using weak or soft reference with a `ReferenceQueue` when is the object really removed from memory? Do I have to call `referancequeue.remove` or  `referancequeue.poll()` methods?

Example:

```
ReferenceQueue q = new ReferenceQueue();
WeakReference wr = new WeakReference(object, referenceQueue);


if (pr.isenqueued()) {

   // do something

}
```

or do I have to following?

```
WeakReference weakref=null;

if ((weakref=q.removed())!=null) {

   // do something

}
```

Answer (score 1):

In your example WeakReference will be cleaned by garbage collector when it's unreacheble. On the other hand if you use SoftReferences, softly reachable objects are kept as long as ther is enough memory. So if you want it to persist you should use SoftReference. I guess having the control i.e. 2nd way would give you a peace of mind. If you want to make the cleanup operations yourself instead of GC, to ensure the progress you can use PhantomReference instead. They aren't automatically cleared by the garbage collector before they are enqueued.

Answer (score 0):

After you remove them from the ReferenceQueue, the object can be finalised and after they have been finalised they can be removed on the next GC.

Comment: do you mean that i have to run "q.remove()" in order to java VM to remove object from memory automatically.

Comment: When you call q.remove() the object can be finalized and after it has been finalized it can be cleaned up. i.e. it might not be cleaned up for one or two more GCs.